# bash script: bad substitution

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am getting a bad substitution error for the following line:

```
cur_hour=${cur_hour:11:2}
```

The relevant code is here:

```
while :
do
    cur_hour=`date`
    cur_hour=${cur_hour:11:2}

    if [ <some comparisons> ]
    then
        <some other code here>
    fi
done
```

When I try the "trouble" code manually it works fine but in the script it causes the error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you running the script? This kind of error happens most commonly when someone writes a script for bash, but runs it with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: `./loop.sh`, where "loop.sh" is the file name

Comment: Is this the entire script? If not, what is the very first line of the script file?

Comment: @JDOdle Make sure the first line is `#!/bin/bash`. It can not be `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: i do have it as `#!/bin/sh` what is the difference here?

Comment: sh is a subset of bash, it does not have the same features as bash. Change the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash` and you should be golden

Comment: Incidentally, if you read the StackOverflow tag wiki for bash, this is one of the things you're supposed to check for before you ask a question here. :)

Comment: ...for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

Comment: Oh, by the way, it's not _merely_ the shebang here; if /bin/sh were a symlink to /bin/bash this particular error would not have happened, because even in POSIX mode bash still implements the substring parameter expansion. To get this particular error, /bin/sh has to be implemented by something other than bash (most likely dash).